# Как проверить на валидность JSON в большом файле по частям?

Tags: python, json, файлы

Принимается файл, в котором записан *JSON* массив. Файл может быть большой (до 200МБ). Необходимо проверить массив на соответствие формату *JSON* (и еще бы хотелось производить форматирование) и записать файл в хранилище. В память все 200МБ загружать не хочется.

Подскажите, как это сделать по частям, так сказать, перекачать данные из одного файла в другой, не загружая весь файл в память?

Например:

```
[
[
  1234,
  1234,
  1234,
  465
],
[
  1234,
  1234,
  1234,
  1234
],
[
  1234,
  1234,
  1234,
  1234
],
[
  1234,
  1234,
  1234,
  1234
]
]
```

Нужно получить.

```
1234,1234,1234,465
1234,1234,1234,1234
1234,1234,1234,1234
1234,1234,1234,1234
```

Comment: можете пояснить что значит "записать файл в хранилище"?

Comment: @MaxU сейчас это просто папка на локальном комьютере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С задачами проверки (валидации) и форматирования JSON неплохо справляется [json.tool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). С файлами до 200МБ проблем возникнуть не должно...

Использование:

```
python -m json.tool json_file.json > formatted_json_file.json
```

PS если всё же необходимо читать по частям то советую обратить внимание на [json-streamer](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer)

Comment: Спасибо. json.tool по-видисмому все равно загружает весь файл в память.

Comment: Думаю  json-streamer. мне подойдет. в крайнем случае есть еще решения на основе yajl.